# Dropdown Opens Once At a Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul li` list which has submenus.  By default the submenus are hidden.  When I click on the first `li a`, this submenu will slide down.  When I click on the second 'li a`, the second submenu will slide down.

A problem is when I click on the second `li a`, the first submenu will be slide up.  That means only one submenu opens at a time.

Please give me a hand.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzyUr/40/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
li {padding:20px; border: solid 1px;margin:5px;}

.square {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List1</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List2</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 2
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List3</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 3
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Hover List4</a>
        <div class="square">
        Square 4
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').on('click', function(){
            $('.square').removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```
li {padding:20px; border: solid 1px;margin:5px;}

.square {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.active {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to know where the 'open' elements are.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li a').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $opened = $this.closest('ul').find('.open');
    $siblings = $this.siblings();
    if (!$siblings.is($opened)) {
      // toggleClass() will work too, but this is more explicit
      $opened.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
      // This will inhibit the closing of an open element if clicked.
      // Move the previous line before the 'if' if you don't want this behaviour.
      $siblings.slideToggle().addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.square {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Hover List1</a>
    <div class="square">
      Square 1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Hover List2</a>
    <div class="square">
      Square 2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Hover List3</a>
    <div class="square">
      Square 3
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Hover List4</a>
    <div class="square">
      Square 4
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, msg and Patrik Alexits so much for sharing your experience!